# xargs on OSX: illegal option --

Tags: osx, xargs

I'm on OSX. I want to run a python script against all pngs in a particular directory. This is what I've tried:

```
find docs/ -name "*png" | xargs --replace=F python myscript.py "F"
```

But I see this:

```
xargs: illegal option -- -
usage: xargs [-0opt] [-E eofstr] [-I replstr [-R replacements]] [-J replstr]
             [-L number] [-n number [-x]] [-P maxprocs] [-s size]
             [utility [argument ...]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your problem is that you memorized non-portable GNUisms instead of using the portable set of options.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`xargs` on Mac OS X](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) doesn't support the `--replace` option; you can use `-I` instead:

```
find docs/ -name "*png" | xargs -I F python myscript.py "F"
```

The strange error message is produced because this version of `xargs` interprets characters after a single `-` as options, so with `--replace` it's looking for an option named `-`, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

[Mac OSX xargs](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/xargs.1.html) does not support long options like [GNU xargs](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/xargs-options.html#xargs-options). For using `--replace` like GNU xargs, use `-I`:

```
find docs/ -name "*png" | xargs -I F python myscript.py "F"
```

Note that this approach breaks with file name contain newline, you want to use `find -print0` with `xargs -0`:

```
find docs/ -name "*png" -print0 | xargs -0 -I F python myscript.py "F"
```

or standard one:

```
find docs/ -name "*png" -exec python myscript.py {} +
```

Comment: In general, it is a good idea to only learn and use the portable standard options instead of using GNUisms. This is why I encourage people to change their mind when someone again send an answer with a non-portable GNUism.

Comment: @schily: Sticking with the standard is good, but we should also offer all the tools available for user.

Comment: More than 90% of the Answers in this forum that use GNUisms could be written in a portable way without giving up any functionality.