# Xargs command works on linux but not on mac

Tags: osx, xargs

I've run the following xargs command on my mac

```
echo replace | xargs -n 1 -I {} echo "asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf{} asd"
```

It gives the output as this, not printing the entire string

```
asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf adf
```

I've tried the same on a linux machine and I get the expected output. Can you tell me how I can make this work on mac?

```
asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdf asdf asdf asdf adf asdfreplace asd
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [xargs on OSX: illegal option --](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/285169/xargs-on-osx-illegal-option)

Answer (score 3):

From the `xargs(1)` man page

```
 -I replstr
         Execute utility for each input line, replacing one or more
         occurrences of replstr in up to replacements (or 5 if no -R
         flag is specified) arguments to utility with the entire
         line of input.  The resulting arguments, after replacement
         is done, will not be allowed to grow beyond 255 bytes;
```

and then if we count the characters generated by your command

```
$ wc -c out
     255 out
```

so you're running into a documented limit. Workarounds would be not to do this (what exactly is the need here for such a long argument?) or to maybe instead install some linux version of `xargs` and call that.